# subset sum variant problem

Tags: np-complete

Given non-repeated list of integers $a_1\dots a_n$, is there $ATLEAST\mbox{ }ONE$ subset of them that sum to $0$.

This problem is NP complete.

Given non-repeated list of integers $a_1\dots a_n$, are there $ATLEAST\mbox{ }TWO$ subsets of them of sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $n_1+n_2=n$ each of which sums to $0$.

Is this problem NP complete?

I am unsure if this problem is straight forward. There is a paper http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~pagour/papers/NJC09.pdf on equal sum variants.

However, the current problem is not shown NP-complete here.

The closest problem discussed there is EQUAL SUM SUBSETs with EQUAL CARDINALITY. This one has COMPLEMENTARY CARDINALITY.

More generally is the following problem NP complete?

Given non-repeated list of integers $a_1\dots a_n$, are there $ATLEAST\mbox{ }K$ subsets of them of sizes $n_1,\dots,n_K$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{K}n_i=n$ and such that each subset sums to $0$.

Comment: Can we specific $n_1$ and $n_2$ in the ATLEAST TWO problem, or do we just get to pick $n$?

Comment: $n_1$ and $n_2$ are arbitrary but $n_1+n_2=n$.